# TomEE Unable to compile class for JSP exceeding the 65535 bytes limit

Tags: jsp, spring-mvc, apache-tomee

I'm getting The code of method _jspService(HttpServletRequest, HttpServletResponse) is exceeding the 65535 bytes limit error in my web application. Its a Spring MVC, Java 8 application which i've deployed in TomEE (v7.0.3). I had tried [solution](https://support.assetbank.co.uk/hc/en-gb/articles/115005208888-How-do-I-fix-a-65535-bytes-limit-Stacktrace-) provided but no luck. JSP doesnt have static includes.

Comment: This error caused by your jsp compiled into a far too large java code.
May be refactor it would be a good idea?

Comment: These are legacy application pages and we are short of resource and time to take this approach.

Comment: Unfortunately that might be the only way, just refactor part of the jsp (move large block of scriptlet into a POJO and invoke from servlet etc.)

Comment: Thanks Kee.. eventually i had to refactor the code in conjunction of using maven to delete all space in the target jsp..